# PJSIP ios is not trying to re-register after getting the nonce due to IP change

Tags: ios, sip, voip, pjsip

I am trying to implement PJSIP for ios using the cocoapod port of the same (https://github.com/petester42/pjsip-ios). I am trying to register an account to my SIP server which is hosted on google cloud using Kamailio(4.4.x). The library is trying to register itself but during that everytime the IP is getting changed. I am using Digest authentication mechanism for which after getting the nonce it is not retrying the registration.

So i looked into the doc of **IPAddressChange** of PJSIP(https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPAddressChange#Approach1:Restarteverything) and there it says on IP change the straight forward way is to destroy everything and restart everything. So for getting the network change event I am using **Reachability**. How do I test the if IP changed or not. In the log the library itself is saying **IP address change detected for account 0 (192.168.100.143:5060 --> 103.78.19.70:5060). Updating registration (using method 4)**, so why the library's default fallback mechanism is not working?

How can I handle this case?

My code looks like this:

```
func setupSIP(){

        var status = pj_status_t()

        pjsua_create()

        var ua_cfg:pjsua_config = pjsua_config()
        var log_cfg:pjsua_logging_config = pjsua_logging_config()
        var media_cfg:pjsua_media_config = pjsua_media_config()

        pjsua_config_default(&ua_cfg);
        pjsua_logging_config_default(&log_cfg);
        pjsua_media_config_default(&media_cfg);

        pjsua_init(&ua_cfg, &log_cfg, &media_cfg);

        var transportConfig:pjsua_transport_config = pjsua_transport_config()

        pjsua_transport_config_default(&transportConfig);

        transportConfig.port = 5060;




        pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &transportConfig, nil);
        //pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP, &transportConfig, nil);

        status = pjsua_start();


        var acc_cfg = pjsua_acc_config()

        var accountId = pjsua_acc_id()
        pjsua_acc_config_default(&acc_cfg);

        acc_cfg.id = giveStruct(string: "sip:1001@105.131.142.101")
        acc_cfg.reg_uri = giveStruct(string: "sip:105.131.142.101:5060")
        acc_cfg.cred_count = 1;
        acc_cfg.cred_info.0.realm = giveStruct(string: "*")
        acc_cfg.cred_info.0.scheme = giveStruct(string: "digest")
        acc_cfg.cred_info.0.username = giveStruct(string: "1001")
        acc_cfg.cred_info.0.data_type = 0;
        acc_cfg.cred_info.0.data = giveStruct(string: "1001")
        acc_cfg.reg_timeout = 1000
        acc_cfg.ka_interval = 5
        acc_cfg.register_on_acc_add = 1
        pjsua_acc_add(&acc_cfg,1, &accountId)
        //print(res)

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.reach = Reachability.forInternetConnection()

        // Tell the reachability that we DON'T want to be reachable on 3G/EDGE/CDMA
        self.reach!.reachableOnWWAN = false

        // Here we set up a NSNotification observer. The Reachability that caused the notification
        // is passed in the object parameter
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged),
            name: NSNotification.Name.reachabilityChanged,
            object: nil
        )

        self.reach!.startNotifier()

        self.setupSIP()
        return true
    }

    @objc func reachabilityChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
        if self.reach!.isReachableViaWiFi() || self.reach!.isReachableViaWWAN() {
            print("Service available!!!")
        } else {
            print("No service available!!!")
        }

        pjsua_destroy()
        self.setupSIP()
    }
```

the log looks like this:

```
19:07:15.820   pjsua_core.c  ...TX 488 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=26388 (tdta0x104049400) to UDP 105.131.142.101:5060:
REGISTER sip:105.131.142.101:5060 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.100.143:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj4J5tZU4KgWii.znUwydBLgJchV699zm7

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:105.131.142.101>;tag=vhaOo652Ovn9Ligxr6-jEFNiClvjvpcj

To: <sip:105.131.142.101>

Call-ID: TNuFgpAt-pPBoCLumKswBsOTETZTYdvj

CSeq: 26388 REGISTER

Contact: <sip:192.168.100.143:5060;ob>

Expires: 1000

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
19:07:15.820    pjsua_acc.c  ..Acc 0: Registration sent
19:07:15.938   pjsua_core.c  .RX 501 bytes Response msg 401/REGISTER/cseq=26388 (rdata0x10404a828) from UDP 105.131.142.101:5060:
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.100.143:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bKPj4J5tZU4KgWii.znUwydBLgJchV699zm7;received=103.78.19.70

From: <sip:105.131.142.101>;tag=vhaOo652Ovn9Ligxr6-jEFNiClvjvpcj

To: <sip:105.131.142.101>;tag=b27e1a1d33761e85846fc98f5f3a7e58.1511

Call-ID: TNuFgpAt-pPBoCLumKswBsOTETZTYdvj

CSeq: 26388 REGISTER

WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="105.131.142.101", nonce="XRN2N10TdQspViwWHFKrPESgdCBqaa1P"

Server: kamailio (4.4.7 (x86_64/linux))

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
19:07:15.939    pjsua_acc.c  ....IP address change detected for account 0 (192.168.100.143:5060 --> 103.78.19.70:5060). Updating registration (using method 4)
19:07:15.939 sip_auth_clien  ...Unable to set auth for tdta0x104049400: can not find credential for 105.131.142.101/Digest
19:07:15.939    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration error: No suitable credential (PJSIP_ENOCREDENTIAL) [status=171101]
```

The main problem is I am not able to register myself even if the passed credentials are correct. I can register myself from linphone with the same username and password. So i am supposing IP change is the reason I am not able to register. Is it so?

Comment: Same problem, when reachabilityChanged i destroy and register new pjsip (if in call, i just call pjsua_handle_ip_change). It work fine, but sometimes my app crash in background (100% iOS 13)

Comment: Bro can I get code for your giveStruct function?